# Apache Solr for production

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr, lucene, lamp

I have chosen Apache Lucene with Solr to learn about advanced search indexing for my web applications but there seems to be a gap in configuration between versions Solr 4 and Solr 5.

Most online material and books get you to setup Apache Tomcat to run the Solr service for version 4. Whereas version 5 tells you to use it using its built-in service.

My web applications are built on the LAMP stack and I would like in the future to use Solr in production and I am wondering what version/configuration is best practice?

Comment: Yes, Solr 5 does not support running within a Tomcat container, so you would have to run it as its own service. This is easy to do, though. And Solr 5 is where the action is as far as new development. As far as best practice is concerned, that will depend upon the requirements of your application.

Answer (score 0):

The latest stable version of Solr is currently 5.4.0. So, that is the version that you should be using unless there is some other constraint that requires you to use an older version.

By default Solr runs in Jetty, but you can also run in in various other servlet containers. Here is documentation for running it inside Tomcat: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat

As far as having a LAMP stack, that shouldn't really have much to do with Solr. You should have a webapp that is accessing Solr and is sitting behind an web server (in your case Apache httpd).